# Handling post request for 2 forms in one page using express

Tags: node.js, express

I have two forms, newsletter signup form and contact form in one page. I want to make post request for both using node and express. How can I do it?

Here's the html code for the forums:

```
<!-- Newsletter signup Section -->

        <section class="newsletter-section">

            <form action="/" method="POST">
                <span class="newsletter-heading u-text-align-centre u-margin-bottom-medium">
                    Subscribe to our monthly newsletter!
                </span>
                <div class="row u-text-align-centre">
                    <input type="text" name="email-address" class="newsletter-input">
                    <a href="#" class="btn-full btn-round newsletter-btn">Sign Me Up!</a>
                </div>
            </form>
        </section>


        <!--contact section-->
        <section class="contact-section">

            <div class="contact-container">

                <h2>Contact Us</h2>

                <div class="container">

                    <div class="customer-info">

                        <form class="contact-form" action="/" method="POST">

                            <div class="name">
                                <div class="first-name">
                                    <label for="first-name">First Name</label>
                                    <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="First Name" />
                                </div>

                                <div class="last-name">
                                    <label for="last-name">Last Name</label>
                                    <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Last Name" />
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="contact-info">
                                <div class="email">
                                    <label for="email">Email</label>
                                    <input type="email" id="email" placeholder="email" />
                                </div>

                                <div class="tel">
                                    <label for="tel">Tel</label>
                                    <input type="tel" id="tel" placeholder="tel" />
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="reason">
                                <label for="reason">How may we help you?</label>
                                <select name="reason" id="reason">
                                    <option value="">Select an option</option>
                                    <option value="Customer-service">Customer Service</option>
                                    <option value="book-event">Book for an event</option>
                                    <option value="place-order">Place Order</option>
                                    <option value="inquiries">Inqiries</option>
                                    <option value="####">Other</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>

                            <div class="short-message">
                                <textarea id="message" rows="10" placeholder="Type a short message here"></textarea>
                            </div>

                            <div class="save-info">
                                <span>Save my info for next time</span>
                                <input type="checkbox" class="final-input" />
                            </div>

                            <div class="submit">
                                <button name="submit" class="btn-round">Send</button>
                            </div>

                        </form>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
```

And this is the code for the node.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const ejs = require('ejs');
const _ = require('lodash');

const app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.static("public"));

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
     res.render('home', { homeContent: homeStartingContent, posts: posts });
});
```

That was all of the code. Now I want to add the post request for each of the forms sepeartely.

Comment: What do you want to do, exactly? When one form is filled out and submitted, what should happen to the other? Do you want to process the data from both forms at once? Or only one at a time?

Comment: How do I make a post request differently for both of them?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to have two forms on one page, each with their own submit button. When the submit button for one form is pressed, it should only submit that form, and not the other. Correct? If so, please share your current implementation

Comment: Yes, this is the thing that I want

Comment: Can you please share the code for your frontend and the relevant part of your backend where you're receiving the POST request?

Comment: Do I need to edit the question for that?

Comment: That would be best!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `action` parameter of each form element to a different URL (eg. `/contact` and `/subscribe` or whatever you prefer), and then create a route in your API to handle requests to each of these.

Currently, with the `action` set to `"/"`, you're sending the output of both forms to the same endpoint in your backend.

```html
<form action="/subscribe" method="POST">...</form>
<form action="/contact" method="POST">...</form>
```

```js
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  // Display the forms
  res.render('home', { homeContent: homeStartingContent, posts: posts });
});

app.post('/subscribe', function (req, res) {
  // Deal with the contents of the submitted subscription form
});

app.post('/contact', function (req, res) {
  // Deal with the contents of the submitted contact form
});
```

Comment: This solved this problem. Thanks! But what if I want to send two forms to same endpoint. Is that ever possible?

Comment: It's possible yes. How you'd implement it depends on what you want to do; whether you want to process both forms at once, or just one, how you'd handle cases such as one form being filled in and the other empty, what if both forms are partially filled it, etc. There's a lot more complication involved.